# Finding mouse target in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I'm trying to add a simple mouse-click tracking to later on complicate it a bit more however I've sort of hit a road block, the code below console logs: `<react></react>` when I click the div and I can't understand why or how to get the div I click on to "become" the target

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MySuperClass extends Component {

  _setPosition (e) {
    console.log(e.target)
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div className='a-class' onMouseDown={() => this._setPosition(event)}>&nbsp;</div>
    );
  }
}

export default MySuperClass;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the DOM event.

```
<div className='a-class' onMouseDown={event => this._setPosition(event)}>&nbsp;</div>
```

Or you can simply do this:

```
<div className='a-class' onMouseDown={this._setPosition}>&nbsp;</div>
```